# IBM Worklight 6.2 Development Server Stops Automatically

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am currently working on IBM Worklight 6.2 in eclipse IDE. My problem is that when I put my PC in idle state for 5 to 10 minutes, Worklight server stops automatically. I don't know the reason. Is this a feature? Is there any way to disable it?

Comment: I think this is feature, and I am not able to find any solution to it untill today.

Comment: Are we talking here about your personal PC development environment in Eclipse? What is "ideal state"? Do you actually mean "sleep mode"?

Comment: Idle state, I mean here is not working on PC for some time(5 or 10 minutes). PC is not going in sleep mode either, I have disabled that.

Comment: Still, are we talking about Eclipse?

Comment: Yes. I mean Eclipse !

Comment: I am not convinced this is related to MobileFirst or Eclipse, but to a different component in your OS that also affected Eclipse.

Comment: But ultimately why would any component of my OS will stop Worklight Server?

Comment: Could be that once entering idle mode while liberty is running it repeatadly looking for a connection until it times out.

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: Don't put your computer to idle mode.

Comment: Same issue here, but with Mobile First Studio 7.1.0 (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.5/wlp-1.0.8.cl50520150305-2202). It regurarely shuts down shortly after being started and there is no indication in the server logs, why so. Seems Eclipse is shutting it down by itself according to a progress message.

Answer (score 1):

My only suggestion here is to not allow the PC to enter "idle mode".

Go to Control Panel, then to Power Management, there choose "never" near "system on idle". This will differ a bit depending on the specific Windows OS version.